# Conditional function for Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How do I create a conditional formula for Google Spreadsheets where:

- If the value of cell A1 is an even number, I want cell B2 to display the value of A1 * 2
- If the value of cell A1 is an odd number, I want cell B2 to display the value of A1 + 1

Here's a basic blueprint for what I want to do:

```
function isEven(input) {
    if(input % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function conditionalFormula(input) {
    if(isEven(input)) {
        //Make cell B1's value equal to A1 * 2
    }
    else {
        //Make cell B1's value equal to A1 + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run this function or call it from within the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I want to call it from within the spreadsheet

Comment: In that case can't you use the formula approach? Otherwise calling the function from a cell you can (and must) let the function return the value, not set it from within the script

Comment: I want to use a script because it's a cleaner approach for me and I want to use that know-how to do other things

Comment: In that case you just need the function to `return input+1` or `return input*2` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just use a combination of the built in [ISEVEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093419) and [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) statements to achieve this?

i.e in cell B1 write:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(A1),A1*2,A1+1)
```

You can then copy and paste it which should automagically increment the cell index.

Comment: This is correct! No need to write any script when Google Spreadsheet has so many inbuilt formulas to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this down a column, use the ARRAYFORMULA function so you do not have to copy it to each cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISEVEN(A1:A),A1:A*2,A1:A+1))
```

will give you a 0 if there is no value

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A), IF(ISEVEN(A1:A),A1:A*2,A1:A+1), ""))
```

Will only multiple the value if the cell in Column A is a number.

In the above examples, the formula goes in row 1 and applies to the entire row.  Change the Range from A1:A to A2:A20 if placed in row 2 and working on rows 2 through 20. Both formulas using A1:A will put a value (a number or blank element) in every cell in the column which contains the arrayformula. The A2:A20 version will only put those values inside cells 2-20.